# Diagonals with Matrices

Tags: java, matrix, diagonal

Currently trying to print a matrix with an output of:

```
0 0 0 0 4
0 0 0 3 0
0 0 2 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

This is my code currently:

```
for(int row=0; row < matrix.length; row++)
        for(int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++)
            if(row+col == matrix[row].length)
```

Obviously not complete. I'm not even sure my logic behind the code is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that should work (assuming the matrix is always square):

```
for(int row=0; row < matrix.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++){
            if(row + col == matrix.length - 1){
                matrix[row][col] = col;
                System.out.print(col+ " "); // Print value
            } else {
                matrix[row][col] = 0; // Set value
                System.out.print("0 ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

We subtracted by 1 in the condition since the length-1 gives us the last index. (reminder that indexes start from 0 and to go length -1)

Answer (score 0):

Assume always square matrix.This should construct your matrix.

```
for(int row=0; row < matrix.length; row++)
{
    //System.out.println("");
    for(int col = 0; col < matrix.length; col++)
    {
        //eg [0][4] = 4 on valid condition [5-0-1] == 4 
        if(matrix.length-row-1 == col)
        {
             matrix[row][col] = col;
        }
        //System.out.print(matrix[row][col]);
     }
}
```

For printing in same step just remove print-comments

Answer (score 0):

Note that the default values in an `int` arrays are `0` because the default value of an `int` variable is `0`. Therefore, you just need to change the values in the required diagonal and leave the rest of the values as they are.

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int SIZE = 5;
        int[][] matrix = new int[SIZE][SIZE];

        // Initialise the matrix
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
                if (row + col == matrix.length - 1) {
                    matrix[row][col] = col;
                }
            }
        }

        // Print the matrix
        for (int row[] : matrix) {
            for (int col : row) {
                System.out.print(col + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0 0 0 0 4 
0 0 0 3 0 
0 0 2 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

I have used the enhanced for loop to print the matrix. You can write it as follows if you wish:

```
// Print the matrix
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
        System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```